# Рисование стрелки на карте в MapKit

Tags: android, kotlin, геолокация, yandexmapkit

Нужно нарисовать стрелку по направлению движения, и первая проблема с которой я столкнулся и не могу найти ответ, это нарисовать хоть какую-то стрелку, пробовал рисовать отдельные линии, и давать им вставлять на карту Bitmap конца стрелки, но решил что это не правильно решение и начал копать нашел какой-то странный метод которые должен рисовать линию и у него есть функция addArrow, но он вообще ничего не выводит,

код что пробовал

```
fun MapObjectCollection.createArrowPolyLine1(
    context: Context,
    points: List<Point>,
    strokeWidth: Float = 2f,
    outlineWidth: Float = 8f,
    color: Int = R.color.white_dark,
    outlineColor: Int = R.color.blue
) =
    this.addColoredPolyline(Polyline(points)).also {
        it.addArrow(
            PolylinePosition(0, 0.9),
            200f,
            color
        )
        
        it.zIndex = 2f
        it.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        it.outlineColor = context.color(outlineColor)
        it.outlineWidth = outlineWidth
    }
```

Что я хочу получить
[image: Что я хочу получить]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку я только спустя две недели нашел решение данной проблемы, оставлю свое решение здесь, пусть следующий кто будет этим заниматься, не будет тратить на это столько времени

```
fun MapObjectCollection.createArrowPolyLine(
    context: Context,
    points: List<Point>,
    strokeWidth: Float = 5f,
    outlineColor: Int = R.color.blue_white,
    outlineWidth: Float = 0f,
    outlineColorArrow: Int = R.color.orange,
    color: Int = R.color.blue_white,
    zIndex: Float = 30f
) = this.addColoredPolyline(Polyline(points)).also {
    (0 until points.size - 1).forEach{ segment ->
        if (segment % 6 == 0){
            it.addArrow(
                PolylinePosition(segment, 0.1),
                30f,
                context.color(outlineColorArrow)
            )
        }
    }
    it.arrows().forEach { arrow ->
        arrow.outlineWidth = 0f
        arrow.outlineColor = context.color(outlineColorArrow)
        arrow.triangleHeight = 10f
    }

    it.outlineColor = outlineColor
    it.outlineWidth = outlineWidth
    it.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
    it.setPaletteColor(0,context.color(color))
    it.setColors(List(points.size - 1){0})
    it.zIndex = zIndex
}
```

смысл прост, создает через `setPaletteColor` цвет и к нему индекс и через `setColors` лист равный по длине количеству сегментов(прямая от точки до точки). состоящий из индекса цвете в который надо окрасить эту прямую - это что касается прямой на которой будут рисоваться стрелки, а для самой стрелки через метод `addArrow` передаем сегмент в котором хотим ее нарисовать, точку на сегменте где нарисовать (от 0 до 1), длину и цвет, остальное думаю разберетесь сами)

Comment: привет, можешь подсказать как в yandex.mapkit на месте placemark отображать svg с сервера?